# Trying to understand the difference in React of children in props object or as the 3rd argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

In JSX when you have

```
<div>hello</div>
```

or

```
<div children="hello"></div>
```

it transpiles down to either passing "hello" as the 3rd argument to `React.createElement` or it's part of the props object.

Is there any difference or benefit in allowing both ways when they seem to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: You can use either, but note if you do both `<div children="hello">world</div>` the nesting (i.e. `world`) will win.

Comment: Ok, so there is no major benefit between the 2 but the nested version takes priority, so that's probably the one to stick with. Thanks